# Visual Studio syntax highlighting / autocomplete not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio does not highlight or autocomplete any Unity3D commands any more. I created a new script when noticing that. I restarted VS, reinstalled VS, also reverted all script changes I made today in my project but the result is still the same. Also I now get errors when trying to open my project file. It says it needs a migration and isn't compatible with the current Visual Studio version installed.

The actual error reads "The application that is based on this project type was not found." [translated from German].

I found similar posts on the web where reinstalling VS resolved the issue. Unfortunately, it did not for me. This is how it looks:

[image]

Anybody knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was able to resolve this issue using [this trick](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-2017-tools-for-unity-where-to-find-a-download.487787/#post-3234920):

*"Do me a favor... if this is Visual Studio 2017... hit your start menu and find Visual Studio Installer... Run it... select "Modify" and select individual components... find Visual Studio Tools for Unity... if it's installed, untick it and uninstall it, then run the installer again and reinstall it. Otherwise, just tick it and install it."*